# Подстановка данных из формы с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery, form

*Ситуация:* есть серия вопросов для диагностики самочувствия пациентов с хроническим заболеванием, которые оформлены с помощью обычного `<form></form>`. Вопросы появляются по очереди один за другим. Данные передаются на сервер после ответа на последний вопрос.

*Задача:* в некоторые вопросы необходимо подставлять предыдущие ответы. Т.е. подстановка должна происходить еще до того, как данные передались на сервер.

Как это можно реализовать с помощью *jquery*?

Простой пример:

```
<form>
  <lable for="iac-name">Здравствуйте! Давайте знакомиться. Как Вас зовут?</lable>
  <input type="text" id="iac-name">

  <lable for="iac-email">{нужно подставить iac-name}, рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?</lable>
  <input type="email" id="iac-email">

  <lable for="iac-headache">После ответа на все вопросы мы вышлем Вам результаты анализа на email {нужно подставить iac-email}. Подскажите, за последние 3 дня у Вас была головная боль?</lable>
  <select id="iac-headache">
    <option>Не было</option>
    <option>Была недолгая головная боль</option>
    <option>Да, голова болела несколько дней</option>
    <option>Меня мучает постоянная головная боль</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

В *jquery* я новичок, поэтому не знаю как и можно ли реализовать такую подставку данных. Но исхожу из таких соображений: раз каждому полю формы можно указать уникальный *id*, то значит можно брать из него данные и подставлять в текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант вот так

```
$( "#iac-name" ).change(function() {
    $("#iac-email").text($( "#iac-name" ).val() + ", рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?");
});
```

Если содержимое

```
<lable for="iac-email">{нужно подставить iac-name}, рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?</lable>
```

Будет иметь вид

```
 <lable for="iac-email">, рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?</lable>
```

Тогда можно так

```
 var text = $("#iac-email").text();
 $("#iac-email").text($( "#iac-name" ).val() + text);
```

**Обновление**

Логика такая, что я поместил в переменную `text` - следующий текст

> , рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?

Затем обновил содержимое добавив введенное имя. Все это выполняется по событию `$( "#iac-name" ).change`. Писал в комметариях поэтому не исключено что где-то допустил ошибку.

Для

```
<lable for="iac-email">{нужно подставить iac-name}, рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?</lable>
<input type="email" id="iac-email">
```

Метод `$("#iac-email").text()` должен вернуть

> {нужно подставить iac-name}, рады знакомству. На какой email нам выслать результаты анализа?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Пробую второй вариант. Что-то не получается. Если я правильно понял, то в Вашем решении логика такая:

1) 'var text = $("#iac-email").text();' // создаём переменную text с содержимым из поля с маркером #iac-email
2) '$("#iac-email").text($( "#iac-name" ).val() + text);' // меняем содержимое с маркером #iac-email на содержимое с маркером #iac-name и добавляем переменную text.

Поправьте меня, если по незнанию я неправильно понял логику.

Comment: Но возникает несколько вопросов. Вопрос 1: в моём простом примере и тег lable, и тег input имеют одинаковый маркер (допустим, #iac-name). JQuery сам понимает что нужно брать данные из поля input и подставлять в lable? Или нужно указывать в коде теги?